# SSL works in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have a website (*[www.e-nexus.de](http://www.e-nexus.de)*), and I try to set an SSL certificate. The certificate works in Chrome and Edge but in Firefox (104.0) it does give an error:

[image]

I activated *ssl-debug* and this is the output (I changed the domain names):

```
[root@rm-2 130 rm2.johndoe.de /usr/local/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/logs]# tail -f catalina.out
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.639 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.640 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS13
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.642 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.646 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (34)": {
  0000: 00 08 04 03 05 03 06 03   02 03                    ..........
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.647 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (28)": {
  0000: 40 01                                              @.
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.647 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (65,037)": {
  0000: 00 00 01 00 01 73 00 20   7E E0 E2 0A 3D 5F C1 07  .....s. ....=_..
             (cut)
  0130: F7 F2 23 E4 18 05 62 88   C5                       ..#...b..
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.657 CEST|ClientHello.java:808|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "D2 14 7F AA BE 53 DC 45 28 1E F1 DE CE 5C 47 E9 74 AA B6 4D 71 77 05 90 D6 E5 15 E3 47 09 D1 4C",
  "session id"          : "2C 40 BF 69 27 7A 56 9B C3 E1 D2 B0 7E DA 21 0A 7E 28 DE 2B 9C 13 18 A8 7E 63 78 5B A2 AB 7C C8",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_12                                                                                                                                                                8_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1                                                                                                                                                                305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC0                                                                                                                                                                0A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_1                                                                                                                                                                28_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=www.johndoe.de
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "unknown extension (34)": {
      0000: 00 08 04 03 05 03 06 03   02 03                    ..........
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 34 E2 D6 33 A8 F1 32 BD   77 B3 17 9C DC DB C4 40  4..3..2.w......@
            0010: EC 49 D3 05 93 5A 6D 5A   CA A1 96 2B 45 C2 C6 08  .I...ZmZ...+E...
          }
        },
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 BB 10 DA E8 84 94 DC   5A 20 EC 1B 99 40 68 85  ........Z ...@h.
            0010: C2 1E 82 AA E5 F7 C0 9A   8A 98 9C 6E 30 CF 87 34  ...........n0..4
            0020: 35 C7 12 B8 DB 43 BB 4E   64 28 83 9B 95 6E 76 31  5....C.Nd(...nv1
            0030: EE AA 71 77 7F 58 B5 96   7C 14 75 B4 83 C5 95 42  ..qw.X....u....B
            0040: F3
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sh                                                                                                                                                                a512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "unknown extension (28)": {
      0000: 40 01                                              @.
    },
    "unknown extension (65,037)": {
      0000: 00 00 01 00 01 73 00 20   7E E0 E2 0A 3D 5F C1 07  .....s. ....=_..
             (cut)
      0130: F7 F2 23 E4 18 05 62 88   C5                       ..#...b..
    }
  ]
}
)
  (I cut the dates here)
  58 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_versions
  58 CEST|ClientHello.java:838|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
  58 CEST|SessionTicketExtension.java:457|Client accepts session tickets.
  58 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: session_ticket
  61 CEST|ClientHello.java:1069|Session not resumed.
  61 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:329|no server name matchers, ignore server name indic                                                                                                                                                                ation
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: server_name
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: status_request
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_groups
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: ec_point_formats
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: signature_algorithms
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: signature_algorithms_cert
  62 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:281|Ignore server unenabled extension: application_layer_pr                                                                                                                                                                otocol_negotiation
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiat                                                                                                                                                                ion
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: extended_master_secret
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_versions
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: cookie
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: psk_key_exchange_modes
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: certificate_authorities
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
  64 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: server_name
  64 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: status_reques                                                                                                                                                                t
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_gro                                                                                                                                                                ups
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: ec_point_form                                                                                                                                                                ats
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:224|Populated with extension: signature_algorithms
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: signature_algorithms_cert
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: application_l                                                                                                                                                                ayer_protocol_negotiation
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: extended_mast                                                                                                                                                                er_secret
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: session_ticke                                                                                                                                                                t
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_ver                                                                                                                                                                sions
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation                                                                                                                                                                _info
  76 CEST|ServerHello.java:450|use cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  77 CEST|StatusResponseManager.java:763|Staping disabled or is a resumed session
     CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:454|No expected server name indication response
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
     CEST|MaxFragExtension.java:292|Ignore unavailable max_fragment_length extension
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: max_fragment_len                                                                                                                                                                gth
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:246|Ignore, no extension producer defined: ec_point_forma                                                                                                                                                                ts
  77 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:364|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protoco                                                                                                                                                                l_negotiation
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_laye                                                                                                                                                                r_protocol_negotiation
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request_v                                                                                                                                                                2
  77 CEST|ServerHello.java:375|Produced ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "5F 2C A6 44 25 82 05 4C 46 4A 6D F8 1C 53 E6 93 7A E9 8C F9 AB 30 43 72 4B 7B 7D 2C 4B 91 96 B1",
  "session id"          : "69 E5 26 55 D8 FE 83 ED 42 EB 24 C9 8C CC 50 C2 0A 5A 0D EB 8E BC CA C3 E0 EE 72 2E 78 19 D3 34",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.680 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:271|Produced server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "04 9B FE B0 17 03 95 B8 8F 89 AA 2B AD 04 25 EE 03 22",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2022-08-05 11:32:31.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2022-11-03 10:32:30.000 CET",
    "subject"            : "CN=www.johndoe.de",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: ocsp
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.o.lencr.org
        ,
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.i.lencr.org/
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 2E B3 17 B7 58 56 CB   AE 50 09 40 E6 1F AF 9D  .....XV..P.@....
        0010: 8B 14 C2 C6                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:false
          PathLen: undefined
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 1A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 70 73 2E 6C 65 74  ..http://cps.let
        0010: 73 65 6E 63 72 79 70 74   2E 6F 72 67              sencrypt.org

        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_Encipherment
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: 1.de
          DNSName: 2.de
          DNSName: 3.de
          DNSName: 4.de
          DNSName: 5.de
          DNSName: 6.de
          DNSName: 7.de
          DNSName: 8.de
          DNSName: 9.de
          DNSName: 10.de
          DNSName: 11.de
          DNSName: www.1.de
          DNSName: www.2.de
          DNSName: www.3.de
          DNSName: www.4.de
          DNSName: www.5.de
          DNSName: www.6.de
          DNSName: www.7.de
          DNSName: www.8.de
          DNSName: www.9.de
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 4B FF A1 9A F9 0D 05   F0 06 E2 15 99 93 36 AA  yK............6.
        0010: 86 E9 14 38                                        ...8
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 91 2B 08 4A CF 0C 18 A7 53 F6 D6 2E 25 A7 5F 5A",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2020-09-04 02:00:00.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2025-09-15 18:00:00.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://x1.i.lencr.org/
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 B4 59 E6 7B B6 E5 E4   01 73 80 08 88 C8 1A 58  y.Y......s.....X
        0010: F6 E9 9B 6E                                        ...n
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:0
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://x1.c.lencr.org/]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        []  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          clientAuth
          serverAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 2E B3 17 B7 58 56 CB   AE 50 09 40 E6 1F AF 9D  .....XV..P.@....
        0010: 8B 14 C2 C6                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "40 01 77 21 37 D4 E9 42 B8 EE 76 AA 3C 64 0A B7",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.",
    "not before"         : "2021-01-20 20:14:03.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2024-09-30 20:14:03.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C4 A7 B1 A4 7B 2C 71 FA   DB E1 4B 90 75 FF C4 15  .....,q...K.u...
        0010: 60 85 89 10                                        `...
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://crl.identrust.com/DSTROOTCAX3CRL.crl]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 70 73 2E 72 6F 6F  ."http://cps.roo
        0010: 74 2D 78 31 2E 6C 65 74   73 65 6E 63 72 79 70 74  t-x1.letsencrypt
        0020: 2E 6F 72 67                                        .org

        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 B4 59 E6 7B B6 E5 E4   01 73 80 08 88 C8 1A 58  y.Y......s.....X
        0010: F6 E9 9B 6E                                        ...n
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.698 CEST|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:478|Produced ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake messa                                                                                                                                                                ge (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "x25519"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 55 2B 68 13 54 7F C8 A8   68 9A 11 D9 5A 07 98 1C  U+h.T...h...Z...
      0010: D7 33 A1 94 C5 8D A6 D4   97 42 CB E3 E4 C2 71 6D  .3.......B....qm
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256"
    "signature": {
      0000: 5F 8E 31 E3 AE 4A 48 55   F6 15 39 64 CC 52 DA DE  _.1..JHU..9d.R..
             (cut)
      00F0: C6 64 E4 BC 59 99 A4 A1   F3 0A 0D B9 4A C3 45 72  .d..Y.......J.Er
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.707 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:618|Produced CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [ecdsa_sign, rsa_sign, dss_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_ps                                                                                                                                                                s_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rs                                                                                                                                                                a_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US, CN=admin, OU="[Committer                                                                                                                                                                , Admins, Developer, Architect, Wiki editor]", O="[johndoe.de]", C=EN, CN=1.com, OU=Access, O=www.johndoe.de, C=DE, CN=SSL.com DV CA                                                                                                                                                                , OU=www.ssl.com, O=SSL.com, C=US, CN=root, OU="[Committer, Developer, Architect]", O="[johndoe.de]", C=EN]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.707 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:97|Produced ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.743 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:372|Consuming client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "1E 30 B0 3C",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=johndoe.com, OU=Access, O=www.johndoe.com, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2000-11-10 24:00:00.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2100-11-10 24:00:00.000 CET",
    "subject"            : "CN=root, OU=[], O=[], C=",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=true
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C7 B9 03 C1 93 32 B4 A0   7B 53 B8 E1 03 E4 4B 37  .....2...S....K7
        0010: 20 FA 9E DF                                         ...
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.746 CEST|TransportContext.java:361|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path validation fa                                                                                                                                                                iled: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)

  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        ... 29 more
  Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
        ... 34 more}

)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.746 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:173|outbound has closed, ignore outbound applicat                                                                                                                                                                ion data
```

Funny thing: in a incognito-tab it works like a charm!

Here is my server-configuration: [config](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420208/increase-articles-size)

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Because I tried connecting to your site from Firefox 104.0.1 (on Ubuntu) without incognito tab and I couldn't reproduce the error. https://imgur.com/a/CSa2fpn

Comment: According to the `Consuming client Certificate handshake message` the client tries to authenticate to server (to achieve mutual TLS) with an obvious invalid certificate. I see some certificate confusion here, probably you have a misconfigured client

Comment: @JAAAY Yes, I still have the problem.

Comment: I believe there is a problem with the client ssl configuration, although this may not be the case. Have you touched any ssl configuration on your client? If the other browsers weren't working I would say that you have misconfigured your Tomcat to ask for client authentication.

Comment: Does clearing the Firefox cache and [refreshing the profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings?redirectslug=reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems&redirectlocale=en-US) change something? How did you generate the self-signed cert? Do you have any plugins/extensions installed in Firefox?

Comment: @JAAAY Indeed I have multiple client-certificates for authentication using the mutual-authenication-mechanism. But all client-certifcates are valid, and even if they are invalid, a ssl-connection must be possible anyway.

Comment: @evilmandarine 1. Clearing the firefox cache did not help. 2. Refreshing the profile did help. The problem gone away. 3. I generated no self-signed certificate. 4. I have adblock and ublock installed as extensions, just like everyone has.

Comment: As per @JAAAY's comment, you probably had at least one invalid/expired certificate in Firefox's cache (user profile). Clearing the profile with the refresh may have forced Firefox to renew it. Hard to say which one it was without being able to reproduce it myself (same version of Firefox, Win10).

Comment: @Grim It would be interesting if you didn't generate any self signed certificates or you didn't import any "test" certificates to see if there is a bug with NSS which is the ssl library firefox uses. But now if you refreshed the profile then I guess we don't have access to the problem anymore?

Comment: I opened it with Chrome & Edge and I see the same problem, both say there's no certificate at all.

Comment: Does your Firefox has some `Authentication Decision` for your website in the `Certificate Manager` (I guess you have had and you removed them by refreshing a profile)? Could you provide output from `openssl s_client <options for client cert auth> www.e-nexus.de:443`/`curl -k <options for client cert auth> https://www.e-nexus.de`, where you use your client cert (I guess you have `C = DE, O = www.e-nexus.de, OU = Access, CN = release-manager.com` client cert, pls?

Comment: @MajidALSarra Ddi you try to use https?

Comment: @JAAAY I think MajidALSarra did try https because I redirect to https if possible.

Comment: @Grim I have noticed that your redirection doesn't always work. Also is this site related to you? https://imgur.com/a/UZFrRo1 I saw some login certificates dialog, maybe this is interferring with your ssl certificates?

Comment: @JAAAY `e-nexus.de` != `www.e-nexus.de`! Both are mine, but `e-nexus.de` is my continuous-integration system. Please ignore `e-nexus.de`, the problem occoures only on `www.e-nexus.de`.

Comment: @Grim Are you sure your server configurations don't overlap with each other? In general, this is not an easy problem to solve because we don't have access to your system. If you want to solve your issue you need to post more information about your server configuration, your client configuration, your ssl setup etc.

Comment: @JAAAY I am sure. If you ping www.e-nexus.de and e-nexus.de you will have two different ip-addresses. They are independend servers. Be aware that chrome(browser) cut the www-part out of the url for some reason. That make it appear that the www.e-nexus.de-site is the e-nexus.de-site.

Comment: @JAAAY I can not add more informations to the post because the size in stackexchange is limited. I try to contact a stackexchange-admin for bigger storage of the post, please be patient. I posted my config in a new ticket, see last link in the question.

Comment: Perfect, have you tried removing the option `certificateVerification` or set it to `none`?

Comment: Website appears to be using an expired certificate, website shows as insecure on Safari, PKIX path validation is most certainly connected to the the certificate itself

Comment: It seems that you browser sends a certificate with CN=johndoe.com, OU=Access, O=www.johndoe.com, C=DE and your server do not recognize it. does your server asks for client certificate? did you add a certificate in firefox? Using FF 104.0.1 (64-bit) I can access your site without certificate error. Probably you should update your trustore adding the ca public cert.

Comment: @JAAAY No, and since I can not reproduce the problem anymore I can not try it.

Comment: @Grim One last question. What is this thing in your bash promt `[root@rm-2 130 rm2.johndoe.de /usr/local/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/logs]`. How is `johndoe.de` related to you?

Comment: @JAAAY Its not, I wrote in the question that I changed the domain names. johndoe.de is not related to be, nor johndoe.com.

Comment: @Grim Okay, so maybe you forgot a dumb certificate in the keystore.

Comment: @JAAAY Hm, you mean the sever's keystore? Well, since a firefox-profile-reset fixes the problem it does not look like a problem to the server. If you mean the client-keystore (client-cert-chain), it works straight forward after firefox-profile-reset, that was not the problem either I think.

Comment: @Grim Are you using the same device for both server and client?

Comment: @JAAAY No, I use the browser at my current location in Berlin. The webserver is located in Falkenstein.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, the problem isn't reproducable anymore. So I will try to analyze some probable causes of the problem with respect to my knowledge and of course with respect the posted log.

Let's start with the first line of the log, from this we can see that something is a bit odd since `rm2.johndoe.de` is the `$HOSTNAME` of the machine and the machine is serving for `www.e-nexus.de`. However, this can neither directly influence the SSL certificate procedure neither influence the DNS records on a Linux server (I don't know about a Windows server) with systemd and systemd-resolved as DNS resolution server. According to `man systemd-resolvd.service` where the `$HOSTNAME` is resolved to the `127.0.0.1`.

```
[root@rm-2 130 rm2.johndoe.de /usr/local/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/logs]# tail -f catalina.out
```

Moving on everything seems fine, it is using TLS1.2 and some unsupported TLS extensions which is fine. We have to note here that the screenshot in the related question states that the firefox is trying to use TLS1.3 and it negotiated a cipher suite correctly, which probably means that the log we see is different from the tls connection of the screenshot. We will mainly focus on the server side since we don't have much information about the client side.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.639 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.640 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS13
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.642 CEST|HandshakeContext.java:305|No available cipher suite for TLS11

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.646 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (34)": {
  0000: 00 08 04 03 05 03 06 03   02 03                    ..........
}
)

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.647 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (28)": {
  0000: 40 01                                              @.
}
)

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.647 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
"unknown extension (65,037)": {
  0000: 00 00 01 00 01 73 00 20   7E E0 E2 0A 3D 5F C1 07  .....s. ....=_..
             (cut)
  0130: F7 F2 23 E4 18 05 62 88   C5                       ..#...b..
}
)
```

Now we start to spot the first problems, the `server_name` is `www.johndoe.de` from the client. Supposing the client is requesting `www.e-nexus.de` the `server_name` doesn't match. From my understanding this is unrelated to if DNS caches have are outdated or not. I also think that there is a chance that this is a client bug related to the caches of the Firefox browser, which as indicated in the comments refreshing the profile of the user fixed the issue.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.657 CEST|ClientHello.java:808|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "D2 14 7F AA BE 53 DC 45 28 1E F1 DE CE 5C 47 E9 74 AA B6 4D 71 77 05 90 D6 E5 15 E3 47 09 D1 4C",
  "session id"          : "2C 40 BF 69 27 7A 56 9B C3 E1 D2 B0 7E DA 21 0A 7E 28 DE 2B 9C 13 18 A8 7E 63 78 5B A2 AB 7C C8",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0x1303), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014)TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=www.johndoe.de
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "application_layer_protocol_negotiation (16)": {
      [h2, http/1.1]
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "unknown extension (34)": {
      0000: 00 08 04 03 05 03 06 03   02 03                    ..........
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 34 E2 D6 33 A8 F1 32 BD   77 B3 17 9C DC DB C4 40  4..3..2.w......@
            0010: EC 49 D3 05 93 5A 6D 5A   CA A1 96 2B 45 C2 C6 08  .I...ZmZ...+E...
          }
        },
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 BB 10 DA E8 84 94 DC   5A 20 EC 1B 99 40 68 85  ........Z ...@h.
            0010: C2 1E 82 AA E5 F7 C0 9A   8A 98 9C 6E 30 CF 87 34  ...........n0..4
            0020: 35 C7 12 B8 DB 43 BB 4E   64 28 83 9B 95 6E 76 31  5....C.Nd(...nv1
            0030: EE AA 71 77 7F 58 B5 96   7C 14 75 B4 83 C5 95 42  ..qw.X....u....B
            0040: F3
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sh                                                                                                                                                                a512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "unknown extension (28)": {
      0000: 40 01                                              @.
    },
    "unknown extension (65,037)": {
      0000: 00 00 01 00 01 73 00 20   7E E0 E2 0A 3D 5F C1 07  .....s. ....=_..
             (cut)
      0130: F7 F2 23 E4 18 05 62 88   C5                       ..#...b..
    }
  ]
}
)
```

In the next part of the log everything looks fine. Note that TLS1.2 is negotiated.

```
  (I cut the dates here)
  58 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_versions
  58 CEST|ClientHello.java:838|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
  58 CEST|SessionTicketExtension.java:457|Client accepts session tickets.
  58 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: session_ticket
  61 CEST|ClientHello.java:1069|Session not resumed.
  61 CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:329|no server name matchers, ignore server name indication
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: server_name
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: status_request
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_groups
  61 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: ec_point_formats
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: signature_algorithms
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: signature_algorithms_cert
  62 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:281|Ignore server unenabled extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: extended_master_secret
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: supported_versions
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: cookie
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: psk_key_exchange_modes
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: certificate_authorities
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
  62 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
  64 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: server_name
  64 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: status_request
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_groups
  66 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: ec_point_formats
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:224|Populated with extension: signature_algorithms
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: signature_algorithms_cert
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: extended_master_secret
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: session_ticket
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: supported_versions
  68 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
  76 CEST|ServerHello.java:450|use cipher suite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  77 CEST|StatusResponseManager.java:763|Staping disabled or is a resumed session
     CEST|ServerNameExtension.java:454|No expected server name indication response
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name
     CEST|MaxFragExtension.java:292|Ignore unavailable max_fragment_length extension
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:246|Ignore, no extension producer defined: ec_point_formats
  77 CEST|AlpnExtension.java:364|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
  77 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:260|Ignore, context unavailable extension: status_request_v2
  77 CEST|ServerHello.java:375|Produced ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "5F 2C A6 44 25 82 05 4C 46 4A 6D F8 1C 53 E6 93 7A E9 8C F9 AB 30 43 72 4B 7B 7D 2C 4B 91 96 B1",
  "session id"          : "69 E5 26 55 D8 FE 83 ED 42 EB 24 C9 8C CC 50 C2 0A 5A 0D EB 8E BC CA C3 E0 EE 72 2E 78 19 D3 34",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "session_ticket (35)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
```

A lot of questionmarks here, because the server sends a wrong certificate, maybe the old certificate was forgotten inside the [configs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420208/increase-post-character-limit). The rest of the certificate chain seems legit.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.680 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:271|Produced server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "04 9B FE B0 17 03 95 B8 8F 89 AA 2B AD 04 25 EE 03 22",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2022-08-05 11:32:31.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2022-11-03 10:32:30.000 CET",
    "subject"            : "CN=www.johndoe.de",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: ocsp
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.o.lencr.org
        ,
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://r3.i.lencr.org/
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 2E B3 17 B7 58 56 CB   AE 50 09 40 E6 1F AF 9D  .....XV..P.@....
        0010: 8B 14 C2 C6                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:false
          PathLen: undefined
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 1A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 70 73 2E 6C 65 74  ..http://cps.let
        0010: 73 65 6E 63 72 79 70 74   2E 6F 72 67              sencrypt.org

        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_Encipherment
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: 1.de
          DNSName: 2.de
          DNSName: 3.de
          DNSName: 4.de
          DNSName: 5.de
          DNSName: 6.de
          DNSName: 7.de
          DNSName: 8.de
          DNSName: 9.de
          DNSName: 10.de
          DNSName: 11.de
          DNSName: www.1.de
          DNSName: www.2.de
          DNSName: www.3.de
          DNSName: www.4.de
          DNSName: www.5.de
          DNSName: www.6.de
          DNSName: www.7.de
          DNSName: www.8.de
          DNSName: www.9.de
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 4B FF A1 9A F9 0D 05   F0 06 E2 15 99 93 36 AA  yK............6.
        0010: 86 E9 14 38                                        ...8
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 91 2B 08 4A CF 0C 18 A7 53 F6 D6 2E 25 A7 5F 5A",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2020-09-04 02:00:00.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2025-09-15 18:00:00.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=R3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://x1.i.lencr.org/
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 B4 59 E6 7B B6 E5 E4   01 73 80 08 88 C8 1A 58  y.Y......s.....X
        0010: F6 E9 9B 6E                                        ...n
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:0
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://x1.c.lencr.org/]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        []  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          clientAuth
          serverAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 14 2E B3 17 B7 58 56 CB   AE 50 09 40 E6 1F AF 9D  .....XV..P.@....
        0010: 8B 14 C2 C6                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "40 01 77 21 37 D4 E9 42 B8 EE 76 AA 3C 64 0A B7",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.",
    "not before"         : "2021-01-20 20:14:03.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2024-09-30 20:14:03.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=ISRG Root X1, O=Internet Security Research Group, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://apps.identrust.com/roots/dstrootcax3.p7c
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C4 A7 B1 A4 7B 2C 71 FA   DB E1 4B 90 75 FF C4 15  .....,q...K.u...
        0010: 60 85 89 10                                        `...
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://crl.identrust.com/DSTROOTCAX3CRL.crl]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.2.1]
        []  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 22 68 74 74 70 3A 2F   2F 63 70 73 2E 72 6F 6F  ."http://cps.roo
        0010: 74 2D 78 31 2E 6C 65 74   73 65 6E 63 72 79 70 74  t-x1.letsencrypt
        0020: 2E 6F 72 67                                        .org

        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 79 B4 59 E6 7B B6 E5 E4   01 73 80 08 88 C8 1A 58  y.Y......s.....X
        0010: F6 E9 9B 6E                                        ...n
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
```

ECDH parameters are sent from the server, everythings look good.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.698 CEST|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:478|Produced ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "x25519"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 55 2B 68 13 54 7F C8 A8   68 9A 11 D9 5A 07 98 1C  U+h.T...h...Z...
      0010: D7 33 A1 94 C5 8D A6 D4   97 42 CB E3 E4 C2 71 6D  .3.......B....qm
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256"
    "signature": {
      0000: 5F 8E 31 E3 AE 4A 48 55   F6 15 39 64 CC 52 DA DE  _.1..JHU..9d.R..
             (cut)
      00F0: C6 64 E4 BC 59 99 A4 A1   F3 0A 0D B9 4A C3 45 72  .d..Y.......J.Er
    },
  }
}
)
```

Now the server asks the client for a client certificate, this is probably caused by the `certificateVerification` of the [config](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420208/increase-post-character-limit). The format is a bit weird but I don't think he lists himself as CA. Then the server is done from his part.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.707 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:618|Produced CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [ecdsa_sign, rsa_sign, dss_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384,rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US, CN=admin, OU="[Committer, Admins, Developer, Architect, Wiki editor]", O="[johndoe.de]", C=EN, CN=1.com, OU=Access, O=www.johndoe.de, C=DE, CN=SSL.com DV CA, OU=www.ssl.com, O=SSL.com, C=US, CN=root, OU="[Committer, Developer, Architect]", O="[johndoe.de]", C=EN]
}
)

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|14|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-6|2022-08-29 23:07:02.707 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:97|Produced ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
```

Client sends his certificate back. From my understanding the certificate is probably self signed but the `DistinguishedName` of the certificate authority that signed it doesn't match the one of the certificate `certificate authorities` that the server can accept and fails with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertPathValidatorException.html) exception which isn't very much informative and indicated that the certificate chain couldn't be trusted. Even CN=`johndoe.com` instead of `johndoe.de`.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.743 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:372|Consuming client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "1E 30 B0 3C",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=johndoe.com, OU=Access, O=www.johndoe.com, C=DE",
    "not before"         : "2000-11-10 24:00:00.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2100-11-10 24:00:00.000 CET",
    "subject"            : "CN=root, OU=[], O=[], C=",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=true
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: C7 B9 03 C1 93 32 B4 A0   7B 53 B8 E1 03 E4 4B 37  .....2...S....K7
        0010: 20 FA 9E DF                                         ...
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)

javax.net.ssl|ERROR|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.746 CEST|TransportContext.java:361|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)

  Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
        ... 29 more
  Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
        ... 34 more}
)

javax.net.ssl|WARNING|15|https-jsse-nio2-443-exec-7|2022-08-29 23:07:02.746 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:173|outbound has closed, ignore outbound application data
```

TLDR : Although there isn't so much information on the issue from the client side and also probably the OP is trying to connect to a different configuration of the server in the posted screenshot. According to the posted logs the server behaves correctly so probably there is something wrong with the client and it is highly probably related to the Firefox caches, but we don't have more information to figure out.

Comment: Johndoe has been obfuscated from www.e-nexus.de in the post only. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe I mentioned in the question that johndoe.de never was part of the real logging-output.

Comment: In Firefox I had 3 client-certificates for www.e-nexus.de: Architect, Developer and Admin. By connecting to www.e-neuxs.de I was not asked by firefox which of the 3 client-certs Id like to use. I assumed he fallback to no-client-cert. But obviously firefox sent one of the client-cert for some reason. Why and how firefox decide what client-cert to use is weird. This could explain the problem.

Comment: @Grim [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1043415/firefox-doesnt-ask-me-for-a-certificate-when-visiting-a-site-that-needs-one) is actually your problem and a solution is posted as well. I will update my answer later today

Comment: Hm, according to the tomcat's documentation about client-certs the xml-attribute `SSLVerifyClient` allowes `optional` and `required`. I set it to `optionalNoCA` what is a optional-value. So I can either choose a certificate or cancel the choosing. If firefox decides on its own that a certificate must be sent it is a bug!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is nothing wrong with your certificate. Proof: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.e-nexus.de

The problem is related with serving pages for the http requests. (Without the "s" of http**s**.)

When you are trying to navigate to http://www.e-nexus.de/ all browsers are informing that the connection is not secure. On the other hand when you try to go [http**s**://www.e-nexus.de/](https://www.e-nexus.de/) it works as you should expect.

So the browsers' behavior are all correct. (All for Chrome, Edge and Firefox, and all with normal/incognito modes.)

As a solution, in your web server directing all http calls to https (and never serving http pages except redirect responses) should be sufficient.

Comment: `When you are trying to navigate to http://www.e-nexus.de/ all browsers are informing that the connection is not secure. `, but I do not try to navigate to http. The question is about https, not http. You give a good general advise to the world that https is better. But it is not helpful for the question. This is a problem in TLS. This is not a question about "Should I use tls?".

Comment: See, I need to support http because not all browsers are supporting the TLS-encodings I grant. So either it is secured throu a modern ssl-encoding. If this is not possible I like every visitor to be aware that the communicatino is not secured.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible anymore. Now the http calls are diverted to https. As I stated previously, your certificate is OK. The message you were receiving was because the connection was through HTTP. So I believe either yesterday http was not being redirected to https or (with a s small probability) if https handshake fails the connection falls back to http. Other then this there is no problem.

Comment: Why do you think the connection was throu HTTP?

Comment: Because I typed "http :// e-nexus.de" and got the error. And when I typed "https :// e-nexus.de", I had never got the error. (Without the spaces.) Correction: Behavior is still there. You can test in Firefox. It seems the link with http and without www does not redirect to https.

Comment: So I mean http :// www.e-nexus.de correctly redirects to https :// www.e-nexus.de . 

But http :// e-nexus.de does not redirect to https :// e-nexus.de

Comment: Ok, but the question was always about https. **Never about http**! As you can see in the screenshot the url is a HTTPS url, not a HTTP url.

Comment: Are you still able to replicate the same behavior (http**s** receiving the error)? The possibility that I can think of is the TLS handshake somehow could have failed. Reasons for this can be, port forwarding to an unsecure port, network problem, unreachable 443 port. Did you do any such network configuration since the original question?

Answer (score -1):

Using Firefox 104.0.1 with https://www.e-nexus.de, the Firefox's Inspect "Console" tab display shows this message. That and other page errors may need to be resolved to get this working with the Firefox browser.

```
Content Security Policy: Couldn't process unknown directive 'script-src-elem'
```

[image]

Comment: CSP is a different thing! CSP is OSI layer 7. TLS is OSI layer 5.

Comment: According to the log the connection failed at TLS handshake, which is long before this warning appears.

Comment: I agree that CSP is important.